# Language-dependent frame titles in mdframed

Tags: babel, languages, mdframed

I am using `mdframed` and defining some environments as follows:

```
\newmdenv[%
    frametitle=Example,%
    linecolor=ctcolormain,%
    backgroundcolor=ctcolormain!15,%
]{example}

\newmdenv[%
    frametitle=Note,%
]{note}
```

Now I would like to be able to define the frame titles for other languages too. How can I make the strings be different depending on the selected language (which is set with `babel`) ?

Comment: Related: [Write a package that is aware of the mainlanguage selected in babel or polyglossia](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/193448)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's the solution:

```
\addto\extrasenglish{%
    \def\mdexampletitle{Example}
    \def\mdnotetitle{Note}
}
% ...add strings for other languages here...

\newmdenv[%
    frametitle=\mdexampletitle,%
    linecolor=ctcolormain,%
    backgroundcolor=ctcolormain!15,%
]{example}

\newmdenv[%
    frametitle=\mdnotetitle,%
]{note}
```